# The dual function g is concave, even when the initial problem is not convex?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Wikipedia reads, "The dual function g is concave, even when the initial problem is not convex, because it is a point-wise infimum of affine functions." Can someone explain this? Maybe provide a basic example? What do they mean by "point-wise" and how does the point-wise infimum of affine functions imply concavity?

I've read similar posts about this on here but they use the same argument without an example or much of a proof.

Comment: What is the context of this quote?

Comment: Oh sorry, it's in the context of the Lagrangian dual function

Comment: Let $f$ be a function. Presumably you're talking about the conjugate $g(y) := \inf_x f(x) - \langle y, x\rangle.$ Note that at each point $y,$ $g$ is an infimum over $x$ of the affine functions $g_x(y) :=f(x) - \langle y, x\rangle,$ and hence is a *pointwise infimum.* Note that since each $g_x$ is affine, it is also concave...

Comment: ... (contd.) Now, a standard result is that the pointwise infimum of concave functions is concave. To see this, recall that the intersection of (any number of) convex sets is convex, and that a function is concave iff its hypograph is convex. But the hypograph of the infimum of a set of functions is the intersection of all the hypographs (Show this).

Comment: A [possible duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/515812/pointwise-infimum-of-affine-functions-is-concave)

Comment: "since each gx is affine, it is also concave" - but isn't an affine function both concave and convex?

Comment: And what is the infimum of a set of functions? If the functions are added together wouldn't this be a point?

Comment: Ooh, I see now. Sorry, thanks, yeah the hypograph of the intersection of various affine functions' hypographs is obviously convex (hence the function is concave).

Comment: Wait, no.. when you say "each gx" do you mean each gx for a given y? But that is just a point?

Comment: ...because otherwise gx(y) is not affine necessarily, it is merely guaranteed to be concave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why I couldn't see it initially but for any given $\lambda$ we have an affine function, x being constant so the basic idea is (just looking at the graph):
[image]

wherein the "x-axis" is lambda and the "y-axis" is the value of the dual function g($\lambda$)